# how to schedule job with the monitoring of cpu,memory, disk io, etc.

Tags: docker, server, bigdata, scheduler, apache-zookeeper

My problem is I have a dedicate server, but the resources are still limited, i.e. IO, memory, CPU, etc. 
I need to run a lot of jobs every day. Some jobs are io intensive some jobs are computation intensive. Is there a way to monitor the current status and decide when to start a new job from my job pool or not.
For example, when it knows the current running job are io intensive, it can lunch a job which do not relay on much of io. Or it can choose a running job which use a lot of disk io, stop it, re-schedule it later.
I come up with the solution with docker,since it can monitor the process, but I do not know such kind of scheduler build on top of docker.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [`docker stats`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/runmetrics/) command in order to get basic metrics on what is running in the containers managed by a docker daemon.

You cannot exactly assign a job to a node depending on its *dynamic* behavior. That would mean to know in advance what type of resource a job will use. Which is not described in docker at all.

Docker provides a way to tag nodes which enable [swarm filers](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/filter/), which would enable a cluster manager like swarm to select the right node based on criteria represented by a tag.

But Docker doesn't know about the "job" about to be launched.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Docker version you're on, you have a number of options for prod. You can use the native [Docker Swarm](http://blog.docker.com/2015/11/swarm-1-0/) (just went GA in v1.9), you can give the more mature [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/) a try or HashiCorp's [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/) (early days) and there's of course Apache Mesos+[Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/). See also this [comparison](http://technologyconversations.com/2015/11/04/docker-clustering-tools-compared-kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm/) for more info on the topic.